# How can I call upon a function after another function is run a certain amount of times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The EnemyDead function is run after the enemy died, and PlayerDead means that the player died. The script then disables the dead object and instantiates a new one, and I want to call upon a game over function once either the EnemyDead function or PlayerDead function has been called upon three times. I just have no clue how to go about doing this. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
IEnumerator EnemyDead()
{
    enemyUnit.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);

    randomInt = Random.Range(0, enemyPrefab.Length);
    GameObject enemyGO = Instantiate(enemyPrefab[randomInt], enemySpawn);
    enemyUnit = enemyGO.GetComponent<Unit>();

    enemyHUD.SetHUD(enemyUnit);

    if (playerUnit.speed > enemyUnit.speed)
    {
        state = BattleState.PLAYERTURN;
        PlayerTurn();
    }

    else if (enemyUnit.speed > playerUnit.speed)
    {
        passButtonDamage.interactable = false;
        attackButton.interactable = false;
        healButton.interactable = false;
        passButtonResistance.interactable = false;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);

        state = BattleState.ENEMYTURN;
        StartCoroutine(EnemyTurn());
    }
}

IEnumerator PlayerDead()
{
    playerUnit.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);

    randomInt = Random.Range(0, playerPrefab.Length);
    GameObject playerGO = Instantiate(playerPrefab[randomInt], playerSpawn);
    playerUnit = playerGO.GetComponent<Unit>();

    playerHUD.SetHUD(playerUnit);

    if (playerUnit.speed > enemyUnit.speed)
    {
        state = BattleState.PLAYERTURN;
        PlayerTurn();
    }

    else if (enemyUnit.speed > playerUnit.speed)
    {
        passButtonDamage.interactable = false;
        attackButton.interactable = false;
        healButton.interactable = false;
        passButtonResistance.interactable = false;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);

        state = BattleState.ENEMYTURN;
        StartCoroutine(EnemyTurn());
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a simple `int` counter you increase and check everytime ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a new function and property that checks for it.

```
    private int _checkForGameOver { get; set; } = 0;

    public void CountGameOver()
    {
        _checkForGameOver++;

        if (_checkForGameOver == 3)
            GameOver();
    }
```

And put this function into the body of both EnemyDead and PlayerDead. When the function is called three times, `GameOver()` will be called. Of course you have to handle ongoing Coroutines!

Comment: thank you!! this makes a lot of sense, and i figured that I would have to do something of this nature, but im relatively new to programming so I didnt know how.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note but you could/should use one single method since basically both your routines do exactly the same things just with different references. You can use the [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) keyword.

And then you could add a simple `int` counter e.g.

```
public Transform playerSpawn;
public Unit[] playerPrefabs;
public <YourType> playerHUD;
[Space]
public Transform enemySpawn;
public Unit[] enemyPrefabs;
public <YourType> enemyHUD;

private int deathCountPlayer;
private int deathCountEnemy;
private Unit playerUnit;
private Unit enemyUnit;

private IEnumerator UnitDead(ref Unit targetUnit, ref int deathCount, Unit[] prefabs, Transform targetParent, <YourType> targetHUD)
{
    // if you instantiate new units you should actually destroy the old
    // ones not only disable their children!
    Destroy(targetUnit.gameObject);

    if(++deathCount >= 3)
    {
        // GAME OVER
        if(deathCountPlayer > deathCountEnemy)
        {
            // enemy wins
        }
        else
        {
            // player wins
        }

        yield break;
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

    var randomInt = Random.Range(0, prefabs.Length);
    // since we passed in targetUnit using the ref keyword
    // this will replace either the playerUnit or enemyUnit reference 
    // we passed in
    targetUnit = Instantiate(prefabs[randomInt], targetParent);

    targetHUD.SetHUD(targetUnit);

    if (playerUnit.speed > enemyUnit.speed)
    {
        state = BattleState.PLAYERTURN;
        PlayerTurn();
    }
    else if (enemyUnit.speed > playerUnit.speed)
    {
        passButtonDamage.interactable = false;
        attackButton.interactable = false;
        healButton.interactable = false;
        passButtonResistance.interactable = false;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        state = BattleState.ENEMYTURN;
        StartCoroutine(EnemyTurn());
    }
}
```

So now you would start the coroutine either using

```
StartCoroutine(ref playerUnit, ref deathCountPlayer, playerPrefabs, playerSpawn, playerHUD);
```

or

```
StartCoroutine(ref enemyUnit, ref deathCountEnemy, enemyPrefabs, enemySpawn, enemyHUD);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is an incredibly detailed, well thought out response, and I'm very grateful... and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Here an example with some properties and events. If you have any question just let me know!!

---

```
public class MyGameHandle
{
    public delegate void OnGameOver();
    public event OnGameOver OnGameIsOver;


    private int _enemyCount = 0;
    private readonly int _enemiesToLoseGame = 3;

    private int _playerDeadsCount = 0;
    private readonly int _playerLifes = 3;

    public int EnemyCountProperty
    {
        get { return _enemyCount; }
        private set
        {
            _enemyCount = value;
            if (_enemyCount >= _enemiesToLoseGame)
            {
                OnGameIsOver?.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }

    public int PlayerDeadsCount
    {
        get { return _playerDeadsCount; }
        private set
        {
            _playerDeadsCount = value;
            if (_playerDeadsCount >= _playerLifes)
            {
                OnGameIsOver?.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator EnemyDead()
    {
        EnemyCountProperty++;
        /*
         *
         *
         *
         */
        yield return null;
    }

    IEnumerator PlayerDead()
    {
        PlayerDeadsCount++;
        /*
         *
         *
         *
         */
        yield return null;
    }

    public class SomeWhereInMyProject
    {
        public SomeWhereInMyProject()
        {
            MyGameHandle gameHandle = new MyGameHandle();
            gameHandle.OnGameIsOver += GameOver;
        }

        private void GameOver()
        {
            //Handle Gameover event

            //YOUR CODE HERE

            /*
             *
             *
             */
        }
    }
```